# Set page as taxonomy term index

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-taxonomy

I've have a custom post called "bakeryequipment". This custom post type has a taxonomy called "machinetype", it contains a term like "spraying-machine". I have several machines linked to this term. I want to create an editable index page (like a normal page), i don't want just an index (that works). I want to set a static normal page as the index.

I made a page called spraying-machine (same slug as the term; bakeryequipment/spraying-machine). if i go the that url, i get the index of that term (with all the machines on there, loading index.php form my theme). I want it to load the static page i created.

How can i set this static page to be the index? I think i need some kind of rewrite order rule? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the best option is to change your page slug. Just change your page slug like "spraying-machines" or "spray-machine".

Because as per the wordpress hierarchy this is the default behaviour when we are having same slug. 
You can change the name or slug of the term as well, but as per me change the page slug is better choice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.If change the name of the page slug it will load the term index (as in a normal index which i cant edit). I want to have the option to adjust east term index to my needs. for example i want a description for each index and several other things (so each index doens't look the same).